# PHP script works on local MAMP server but not IIS 8 server

Tags: php, iis, json, twitter

I have a PHP script that displays Tweets embedded in a site I built out on my local machine. When I uploaded the site to my IIS 8.0 server, the PHP script no longer works and I receive this error:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\i360_new\footer.php on line 76

The script is:

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');

    /** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
    $settings = array(
        'oauth_access_token' => "xxxxx",
        'oauth_access_token_secret' => "xxxxx",
        'consumer_key' => "xxxxx",
        'consumer_secret' => "xxxxx"
    );


    /** Perform a GET request and echo the response **/
    /** Note: Set the GET field BEFORE calling buildOauth(); **/
    $url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";
    $getfield = '?screen_name=interactive360&count=1';
    $requestMethod = 'GET';
    $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
    $string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
    ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
    ->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);
    foreach($string as $items)
        {
            echo $items['text']."<br />";
        }
?>
```

I thought it might be a PHP version issue but my local machine is running 5.4.10 and my server is running 5.4.14.

Comment: Which line is line 76? "Warning" is not an error -- "warning" can often be completely ignored. Put a "print_r($string)" lin in just before the foreach() to see what is actually in that sucker

Comment: $string is actually returning empty which is causing the error. I don't know why it's returning empty though.

Answer (score 1):

Did you compare both servers phpinfo()? While running in almost the same environment each server can work differently depending on which modules are installed.

Comment: The only comparison I did was the version number. Is there something else I should specifically be looking for? They also both have JSON 1.2.1 enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to make sure that the $string isn't empty. I believe a ForEach will throw this error if you provide a string that is empty. It looks like the string depends on TwitterAPIExchange.php, I see the 'Require Once', but ensure it's configured correctly.

Comment: Actually, it looks like you are correct. The $string variable is returning empty. I looked through TwitterAPIExchange.php and the only thing that I noticed might be the problem is that is uses CURL. My IIS server has CURL enabled though.

Comment: Could this possibly have something to do with user permissions on the IIS side?

Comment: Have you checked to see what $twitter has in it? I'm assuming that $settings hasn't changed since you copied it over to production, but might wanna check that as well.

Comment: Ok so when I echo $twitter I get this error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class TwitterAPIExchange could not be converted to string in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\i360_new\footer.php on line 80

Comment: Don't do "echo" do "print_r( $twitter );" -- you can't "echo" an Object

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was an SSL/CURL issue. In the TwitterAPIExchange.php file, I had to add these two lines to the CURL options array:

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false
```